# Computing the convex conjugate of this function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R^+$, $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$, and $b, y \in \mathbb R^m$, and
$$
G(r) = \frac{1}{2} \| r\|^2_2 + \lambda \| x\|_1 + \langle y, Ax - b - r\rangle, \quad r \in \mathbb R^m.
$$

Compute $G^*$, the convex conjugate function of $G$, given by

$$
G^*(z) = \sup_{u} (\langle z, u\rangle - G(u))
$$

This is my attempt:

\begin{align*}
G^*(z) &= \sup_{u} (\langle z, u\rangle - G(u))\\
&= \sup_{u}(\langle z, u\rangle - \frac{1}{2}\| u\|^2_2 - \langle y, Ax - b - u\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1)\\
&= \sup_{u}(\langle z, u\rangle - \frac{1}{2}\langle u, u\rangle - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle + \langle y, u\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1)\\
&= \sup_{u}(\langle z, u\rangle) - \frac{1}{2}\langle u, u\rangle + \langle y, u\rangle) - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1\\
&= \sup_{u}(\langle z + y , u\rangle - \frac{1}{2}\langle u, u\rangle) - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1\\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\| z + y\|^2_2 - \langle y, Ax - b\rangle - \lambda \| x\|_1
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it is correct.

The last two terms of the solution is obvious.

To evaluate $\sup_u \langle z+y, u \rangle - \frac12 \langle u, u \rangle$,

To fidn the optimal $u$, we can differentiate it and equate it to $0$.

$$z+y -u=0,$$ hence the maximum value is attained at $z+y$.

$$\langle z+y, z+y\rangle-\frac12\langle z+y, z+y\rangle= \frac12\langle z+y, z+y\rangle=\frac12\|z+y\|^2_2$$